# Ant copy file to leaf directory

Tags: java, configuration, ant, build-process, build

I'm trying to use [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) and using ant for my build tool.  I have one namespaced class, and when ant builds it of course sub-directories.  I need to put my .xml configuration file in the leaf directory (ie: ${build}/com/cross/xxx/).  Is there an automated way to do this, or do I just manually configure the path of the leaf folder?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question.  You need to copy an XML configuration file *before* the build, *after* the build?  What do you mean "manually configure the path of the leaf folder"?

Comment: After the build, into the "output" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Ant [`copy`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task.  You'll want to do something like this (assuming a name `config.xml` for your XML config file):

```
<copy file="config.xml" todir="${build}/com/cross/xxx/" preservelastmodified="true"/>
```

Of course, `preservelastmodified` is optional.  The copy task is very powerful; above is the simplest possible sample of what it can do.

Comment: But specifically is there away to have the command infer /com/cross/xxx ?

Comment: @carej Ant seriously needs that new mind reading feature suite.

Answer (score 0):

You would store your xml in the required directory in your project, either with the source file or prefereably in a separate tree  eg. resources/com/cross/xxx
And simply copy the entire directory tree to your build directory